# Equation of curve orthogonal to level sets

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Question 1)**

I want to find equation of the curve in $xy$ plane such that it is crosses and orthogonal to all level sets of the function $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4$ and crosses of the point $(1,1)$

My attempt for solving question:

I know that $\nabla f$ is orthogonal to level sets, But how do I can use this to find equation?

**Question 2)**

Consider $g$ as a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. and $g$ is derivable

Show all planes tangent to $z=yg(\frac{x}{y})$ cross $(0,0,0)$

honestly, I have no idea to solve this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1** 
The curve $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ must satisfy $\dfrac{d\gamma}{dt}=\nabla F$ and $\gamma(t_0)=(1,1)$ for some $t_0$

$\left(\dfrac{dx}{dt},\dfrac{dy}{dt}\right)=\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}\right)$ or

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=4x^3$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=4y^3$

Decoupled ODE's easy to solve.

**2** Consider $G(x,y,z)=yg\left(\dfrac xy\right)-z$

The vector $\nabla G(x_0,y_0,z_0)=\left(\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0,z_0),\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0,z_0),\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial z}(x_0,y_0,z_0)\right)$ is ortogonal to the tangent plane to the surface $G(x,y,z)=0$, at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. From elementary geometry, the tangent plane at that point has as equation
$\pi:\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial x}X+\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y}Y+\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial z}Z-\left(\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial x}x_0+\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial y}y_0+\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial z}z_0\right)=0$.

From here we can check if $(0,0,0)\in\pi$

Comment: thanks, but for first question I find $y=x$ as the solution. is it correct? @Rafa

Comment: Yes, that's the solution with the given initial condition.